# Property allowing attribute access

Tags: python, django

To make [part of the django-tables2 API](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/issues/485) usable in templates, I want to define a property on a class that translates the attribute name to an argument to another method.

The current implementation looks (vaguely) like this:

```
class Row(object):
    _cells = {'first_name': 'James', 'last_name': 'Charland'}

    def get_cell(self, name):
        return self._cells[name]
```

This makes it impossible to access a specific cell from a django template, because django templates do not allow passing arguments to functions.

I want to support something like `row.cell.first_name`, which would be easy if the internal structure contained a dict `_cells`. In reality, [the implementation](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/632a95266e6eca9b40723652d442f006faddcbd2/django_tables2/rows.py#L174-L183) is a bit more complex (getting the value involves calling a function). Computing a dict for all possible cells is not desirable either because it might involve doing unnecessary work.

My naive solution looks like this:

```
class Row(object):
    _cells = {'first_name': 'James', 'last_name': 'Charland'}

    def get_cell(self, name):
        return self._cells[name]

    @property
    def cell(self):
        class CellReader(object):
            def __init__(self, row):
                self.row = row

            def __getattr__(self, name):
                return self.row.get_cell(name)

        return CellReader(self)
```

Which works and doesn't use too much code, but it feels a bit verbose. Is there something in the standard library I did not think of to implement this functionality in a more concise way?

Comment: From what I remember, django templates try a lookup with their dot notation, too, so defining `__getitem__()` might be better in your `CellReader`, but apart from that, looks good to me.  This should be posted over at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead, though, as you already have working code.